# How do I convert only the special characters of a String to unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

It's simple, I would like to convert the string characters into Unicode.

E.G:

```
String txt = "fiancé bla";
System.out.println("Converted: " +  someMethod(txt) );
```

The output I'm looking for is: `Converted: fianc\u00e9 bla`. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Apache Commons Lang3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2) library, specifically **StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String)**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("fiancé bla"));
    //outputs fianc\u00E9 bla
}
```